# Android layout - making certain objects expandable

Tags: android, android-widget

Given a horizontal LinearLayout in Android, I'd like to create:

(1) a textbox which fills nearly the width of the screen, except leaving enough space for...

(2) a button on the right

So I create an EditText and a Button and they're both very small.

```
 <LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content">
 <EditText android:text="" 
   android:id="@+id/Text01"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content">
 </EditText>
 <Button android:text="+"
   android:id="@+id/Button01"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_gravity="right">
 </Button>
 </LinearLayout>
```

I can't set the EditText to android:layout_width="fill_parent" otherwise it would obliterate the button.  So how to make the EditText expand as much as it can?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content">
 <EditText android:text="" 
  android:id="@+id/Text01"
  android:layout_width ="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_weight="1">
 </EditText>
 <Button android:text="+"
  android:id="@+id/Button01"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_gravity="right">
 </Button>
 </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: "Error: integer types not allowed (at 'layout_width' with value '0')"

Comment: that gives only a very small textbox on the left, with the button next to it on the left

Comment: Do you have more to your layout than what you showed in your original question?  Because the answer I gave gives me exactly what you are asking for.  I edited my answer above to have the entire contents of the layout file.  I just tested that in Eclipse and it gives exactly what it sounds like you are looking for.  But if this is just part of a bigger layout file, then there may be some other things you need to do to the other elements in your layout to get everything to work.

Comment: yes this is within a vertical linear layout, which is fill_parent and fills the whole screen-width.  will post its xml later

Comment: oops, you were right - there was a top-level layout that didn't have fill_parent.  sorry about that!